# Incremental Load by Using Stored Procedure in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I need to perform an Incremental Load in SSIS by using Dynamic SQL Stored Procedure. Stored procedure is the Source Data to get the tables whatever we need to perform an Incremental load tables. I'm unable to perform incremental load Below is the stored Procedure. Could you please suggest me the procedure to perform incremental load.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100) = '';
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(100) = '';
DECLARE @LAST_DL_TIME_STAMP DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

DECLARE @MIN INT = 0, @MAX INT = 0;

SELECT @MIN = MIN(SNO), @MAX = MAX(SNO) FROM LIST_TBL_DATA_LOAD_TABLES_COLUMNS;

WHILE (@MIN <= @MAX)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME, 
        @COLUMN_NAME = COLUMN_NAME,
        @LAST_DL_TIME_STAMP = LAST_DL_TIME_STAMP
    FROM LIST_TBL_DATA_LOAD_TABLES_COLUMNS
    WHERE SNO = @MIN;

    -- Use CTE for source data
    SET @SQL = 
        'SELECT * 
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME) + ' 
        WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + ' >= (
                                    SELECT LAST_DL_TIME_STAMP 
                                    FROM LIST_TBL_DATA_LOAD_TABLES_COLUMNS 
                                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TABLE_NAME + ''' 
                                    AND COLUMN_NAME = ''' + @COLUMN_NAME + '''
                                )';
    EXEC(@SQL); 

    SET @MIN = @MIN + 1;
     END;

    END;
```

Could you please suggest me the procedure to perform incremental load. I'm failing at the for each loop container.